# Where is 'max_num_of_trees_in_the_forest' parameter in Emgu C# MCvRTParams?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I want to train a Random forest of 500 trees.
In OpenCV, there is a parameter under [CvRTParams](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html#cvrtparams-cvrtparams) called: max_num_of_trees_in_the_forest.

I cannot find this parameter in Emgu equivalent object: [MCvRTParams](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/22a7f4f4-5976-c63c-acce-d23817b79e96.htm).

So how could I build a model consisting of 500 random trees in the absence of this parameter in the managed Emgu object?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the [termCrit property](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/bf1566a8-b0a2-e2e7-45a7-92a5546820d7.htm). For example:

```
MCvRTParams p = new MCvRTParams();
p.termCrit.max_iter = 500;
```